# Is a conjugacy class of $G$ a subgroup of $G$? Proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It's surprising how no website mentions this. Probably because it's obvious, I think it is a subgroup but it's more of like me having trouble with the proof.

So to make sure that I am talking straight, my understanding of what a conjugacy class is,

> For some $a \in G$, the conjugacy class of $a$ over $G$ is $conj_{G}(a)=\{gag^{-1}|g \in G\}$.

So basically, every possible element that $a$ travels around in $G$ as it is operated with $gag^{-1}$ so it's basically the orbit of the operation of conjugacy, yes?

Well, I tried showing closure to start with and immediately get stuck

> Let $g_i,g_j \in G$ such that $g_iag_i^{-1} \neq g_jag_j^{-1}$. So they are in the conjugacy class of $a$ over $G$. Then $(g_iag_i^{-1})(g_jag_j^{-1})$ gives...gives...

uhm,  that's where I get stuck.I want to show $(g_iag_i^{-1})(g_jag_j^{-1}) \in conj_G(a)$  but no idea how from here.

Or wait, does this imply it's not a group after all?

There's absolutely no mention of this as fr as I'm concerned in any webpages so help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is precisely one conjugacy class that contains the identity element.

Comment: It's good to ask yourself questions like this, but you need to investigate examples. Writing down all conjugacy classes of *any* nontrivial group would have shown you that this is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a subgroup because it does not contain the neutral element (except for the class of the neutral element of course, which is the trivial subgroup).

Answer (score 0):

No not generally. Only trivially for the Conjugacy class of the identity element, e.

If $axa^{-1}=e $ then

$a^{-1}axa^{-1}a=a^{-1}ea $

$x=a^{-1}a $

$x=e $.

This shows e is in its own conjugacy class.

And since no other conjugacy class has e (see above) they can't possibly be groups.